# How can i send email attachments from a MQTT Message?

Tags: mqtt, node-red

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

import base64

import cv2

import os

image_path = 'D:\savedimages'

with open(image_path, "rb") as imageFile:

string = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())

publish.single("pi/obj/image", payload=(string), hostname="192.168.0.3")
```

Comment: Are you sure, you wish to send an email using MQTT, because that is not possible.

Comment: Why do you want to use python here? It adds nothing to the use case

Comment: @TrishantPahwa, I am sorry for my bad explanation, I uses Node-RED to send emails. MQTT node is used in Node-Red to receive and give information to the email node in Node-red to send emails.

Comment: @hardillb, I am sorry for my bad explanation, I uses Node-RED to send emails. MQTT node is used in Node-Red to receive and give information to the email node in Node-red to send emails.

Comment: So this question has nothing to do with python

Comment: @hardillb, it is related as i uses python to do this coding

Comment: But Node-RED doesn't care how you create the MQTT message, it's just a MQTT message. Your question is about how to take that message and send it as an email

Comment: Do you have a GitHub repository where it can be easier to understand your code.

Comment: @TrishantPahwa, i do not have a github repository. I have updated my code above. I am trying to open a directory where the directory contains images, and use Node-Red to send those images as email attachment. Because i cannot directly communicate with node-red, hence i use mqtt to do publishing and subscribing. I have no issues sending out the email without attachments. But when attachments is added, thats where the issue comes.

Comment: Try to print the string variable.

Comment: @TrishantPahwa.  printed it. it prints out many characters.b'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

Answer (score 0):

This question is far too broad to get a proper answer.

But in general, MQTT messages are just a collection of bytes, how you format the message payload is entirely up to you, so if you want to turn a message into an email, you will need to write something that unpacks what ever message format you choose and convert it into the `msg` structure that the Node-RED email-out node expects.

As described in the sidebar help for the email-out node:

> you may provide msg.attachments which should contain an array of one
> or more attachments in [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/) format.

Comment: I tried using this code of command to send emails with attachment but it did not works.  import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
import base64
string = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
publish.single("pi/obj/image", payload=(string), hostname="127.0.0.1").

Comment: "but it did not work" is meaningless. Edit the question to include EVERYTHING you have tried, specifically what you tried on the Node-RED  side and explain what didn't work in what way.

Comment: I have put in the code i used to send email which is currently not working in the answers section. Please have a look. Thanks